# ng-show and get element by id both are not working in ng-repeat table?

Tags: html, angularjs, getelementbyid, angularjs-ng-show

I am trying to use `document.getElementById` that is easy also ng-show in Angular.js

I have table in which dynamically populated with three button at each row, when I click select button it shows me the remaining two buttons that are hidden for that row.

```
<td>
   <a ng-click="vm.Select(Survey.Id)" title="{{ 'Select' | translate }}">
   <i"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i>
   <i></a>
</td>                     
<td id=id="{{Survey.Id}}" style="visibility:hidden" >hidden">
   <a ng-click="vm.Update(Survey.Id)" title="{{ 'Update Visit' | translate }}">
   <i"><i class="fa fa-save fa-1x"></i>
    <i></a>
 </td>
 <td id=id="{{Survey.Id}} ng-show="updateicon" >">
    <a ng-click="vm.AddTask(Survey.Id)" title="{{ 'Add Task' | translate }}">
    <i"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>
    <i></a>
  </td>
```

On select click:

```
vm.Select = function(value) {
  var test = value;
  $scope.updateicon = true;
  document.getElementById(value).style.visibility = "visible";
};
```

On click get the element by id not showing me any button while `ng` shows me button for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

While using AngularJS it is recommended to use ng-show/hide. Actually ng-if is even a better choice as it doesn't create a DOM element unless the condition is true.

Anyway in your code yo are missing the brackets in the function call:

```
<a ng-click="vm.Update({{Survey.Id}})" title="{{ 'Update Visit' | translate }}">
```

instead of

```
<a ng-click="vm.Update(Survey.Id)" title="{{ 'Update Visit' | translate }}">
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use `ng-show` or `ng-if`. It is definitely not recommended to use plain JavaScript `document.getElementById()` with AngularJS as it could lead to unforeseen issues since JavaScript directly manipulates the DOM.

You are seeing the buttons for all the rows because every row is tied to the same variable `updateicon` on `ng-show`. You will need some sort of unique ID to access each element in your `surveys` array. You can use the `$index` or `survey.id` (if it is unique to each row) to do this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="survey in surveys track by $index">
  // Insert cells here
  <td>
    <a ng-click="vm.Select($index)" title="{{ 'Select' | translate }}"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i></a>
  </td>
  <td id="{{Survey.Id}}" ng-show="canModify[$index]">
    <a title="{{ 'Update Visit' | translate }}"><i class="fa fa-save fa-1x"></i></a>
  </td>
  <td id="{{Survey.Id}}" ng-show="canModify[$index]">
    <a title="{{ 'Add Task' | translate }}"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
vm.Select = function(index) {
  $scope.canModify[index] = true;
};
```

If you would like to use `survey.id` instead of `$index`, simply replace `$index` in the HTML with `survey.id`.